# Mongoose FindOne - only return fields which match condition

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, conditional-statements

I am trying to query my collection of matches (games) and find if a certain user has already sent data to the 'reportMessages' array of Objects.

```
const results = await Match.findOne({ 'users': req.params.userIdOfReportSender, '_id': req.params.matchId, 'reportMessages.sentBy': req.params.userIdOfReportSender }, 'reportMessages' )
```

However, the above query returns the following:

```
{
  _id: 5fd382c65d5395e0778f2f8a,
  reportMessages: [
    {
      _id: 5fd610f27ae587189c45b6ca,
      content: 'jajatest',
      timeStamp: 2020-12-13T13:02:42.102Z,
      sentBy: 'XbVvm6g3nsRmPg3P1pBvVl84h6C2'
    },
    { sentBy: "'anotheruser123" }
  ]
}
```

How can I get it to only return the first reportMessage, i.e. the one sent by XbVvm6g3nsRmPg3P1pBvVl84h6C2?

Mongoose findOne docs (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) show that you can provide arguments to say which fields to select (in their case 'name length' but don't show a way to only select the fields in case they match a certain condition.

Is this even possible? Tried googling this seemingly easy question for quite some time without success

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get only the subdocument you want with this aggregation query:

```js
Match.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { _id: req.params.matchId }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            reportMessages: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$reportMessages',
                    as: 'msg',
                    cond: { $eq: ['$$msg.sentBy', req.params.userIdOfReportSender] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            reportMessage: { $arrayElemAt: [ '$reportMessages', 0 ] },
        }
    },
    { $replaceWith: '$reportMessage' }
]);
```

Note that you only need to specify the document `_id` to get a single result, since `_id`s are unique.

Comment: Thank you. After wrapping ObjectId around req.params.matchId in the $match condition it worked.
Still not sure why that has to be done for this aggregation query, but e.g. in an 'updateOne' operation I don't have to wrap ObjectId around it and can keep using the req.params.matchId value (which I believe is a string).